# How discover the point of an object that balance it weight?

Tags: geometry

My brother have a camera (Nikon 7100 plus attached 18-140 mm lens) and is building a fly-cam himself.

I need to know where is the point in the camera on the x-axis where the weight become balanced.

The camera already have a hole for mount a tripod, but is unbalanced for my purpose.

We don't know what to do apart of test-error.

I don't even know how tag this.

Comment: Are you planning to drill a hole somewhere else?

Comment: Why not mount it as-is and rig a counterweight on what you're going to mount the camera on?

Comment: No, that will ruin the camera. I plan to move the camera to his new center.

Comment: @John That was our first instinct. But is also trial-error and my brother think is the camera unbalance the main problem.

Comment: The only real way might be through suspension, when you suspend an object, the Center of gravity lies on a line directly under the point of suspension, then when you suspend from a different point you get a new line which intersects the first line at the COG, this however might be hard to do with the camera. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass, this link has a section detailing such a method. Since you are only concerned with the COM along the lens/body axis you can treat it as a roughly 2D problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively easy way to find the center of mass of a broomstick: Stretch out both hands quite a distance apart, place the broomstick upn them, then slowly move your hands closer together. They will meet under the center of gravity. That's because at the point which is further apart from the center of gravity, the broomstick gets pressed to your hand less strongly than at the other point, so it will slide more easily. If you want illustrations for this, please look at e.g. [this page](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/experiments/exp/balancing-brooms/).

If your camera has a sufficiently flat and smooth bottom surface, and if your *x* axis (which you did not specify precisely) is parallel to that surface, then you can do the above to locate the center of mass. For added precision, use two identical slim blades (e.g. back of two table knifes) to get better resolution than a pair of thick fingers would provide. And of course you'd like for a second person to hold on to the camera using some string or similar, since chances are that you will drop it at some point and it would be a shame to have it hit the floor.

If this does not work because one of my assumptions doesn't hold, you might suspend the camera from a fixed point. The center of mass will be directly below that point, at least as long as you can neglect whatever rigging you're using to suspend it. So perhaps use thin strings but do all of this a low height above a mattress.

You could also perhaps do your trial-and-error approach with a bit more sophistication. If you place a taunt string under the camera and lift it, the camera will lift on the lighter side and stay on the ground on the heavier side. So now you know which side of the string the center of gravity has to be, and if you marked where you put the string (or used tape to fix it in place), you can now rule out a portion of its bottom surface area. Find a second position where it tips in the opposite direction, and you know that the center of mass has to be somewhere above the region between these two lines. Now you can do manual bisection: tape the string in the middle between the previous two positions and check which direction the camera leans now. Then repeat that process. At each step, the region where the center could be will be cut in half, so you'll reach reasonably high precision very quickly.